# Fixed file name length of increasing numbers with bash

Tags: python, bash

I have files with names fixed to 4 characters in length. They look like:

> 0000.png, 0001.png, ... , 0027.png, ..., etc...

They're increasing integers, 0, 1, ..., n. Zeros are padded to the additional space which the number itself does not fill so that the full file name is 4 characters.

In python, I can loop through these files with something like:

```
for i in range(n):
    file_name = '0'*(4-len(str(n))) + str(n) + '.png'
```

How do I achieve the same effect with bash? I'm not great with bash, so '0' padding part is throwing me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
n=5
for ((i=0;i<=$n;i++)); do 
  printf -v file_name "%0.4d.png" $i
  echo $file_name
done
```

Output:

```
0000.png
0001.png
0002.png
0003.png
0004.png
0005.png
```

Comment: I was not familiar with this usage of `printf`. Guess I should look into into more.

Comment: This is possible, too: `n=5; for i in $(seq -f "%04.0f" 1 $n); do file_name="$i.png"; echo $file_name; done`

Comment: With a fixed range this is possible, too: `for file_name in {0001..0005}.png; do echo $file_name; done`

Comment: Strange, I have successfully tested it with bash 4.2.8 and 4.3.11.

Comment: It must be relatively recent because I'm running 4.1.2. I don't have access to newer version, so I'll just take your word for it :) Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too:

```
n=5
for ((i=0;i<=n;i++)); do 
  filename=$(printf "%0.4d.png" $i)
  echo $filename
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try globbing

```
for x in [[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]].png; 
do 
    echo "$x";
done
```